# How to drop specific dates and times from a data frame in r?

Tags: r, date

I just started in r without programing background. I need help to exclude some specific dates and times from my data frame. The data frame is full year of measurements stored as hourly averages. Some full days need to be removed. I tried to use the below code to remove these days in DD, but the result show only removing only the first hour of these days, how I can remove the whole 24 hours?

```
DD <- 
 as.POSIXct(c("2021-06-01", "2021-06-02","2021-06-03","2021-06-08","2021-06-09",
              "2021-06-10","2021-06-11","2021-06-12","2021-06-13","2021-06-14","2021-06-15", 
              "2021-06-16", "2021-06-17", "2021-06-18", "2021-06-19","2021-06-29", "2021-06-30",
              "2021-07-01","2021-07-03","2021-07-04","2021-07-05","2021-07-06","2021-07-07",
              "2021-09-26", "2021-09-28"))


`%notin%` <- function(x,y) !(x %in% y) 

XYZ<- GH %>% filter (date %notin% DD)
```

Comment: Would you share an example of tour original data.frame (I guess `GH`). You can do it by `dput(head(GH, 10))` or in similar way. I will help to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Your data is only dates, no hours. We can not reproduce your problem with the data provided

Comment: I am sorry, I couldn't upload a sample.  DD is just selection of the dates to be dropped from the original data frame (GH) that contains about 80 columns and 6000 raw (one raw for each hour in the year).  I need to drop the selected 24-hours those in DD days from the original data frame (GH), then the new data frame will be named XYZ. It remove only the first hour of the selected days in DD when I try to use the above code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.